# spring 3.0.5.RELEASE views

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing an application with spring 3.0.5.RELEASE
This is my spring-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

This is my web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
   <display-name>Devices Manager</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/sigfox/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my controller:

```
    @Controller
    @SessionAttributes("loggedUser")
    public class DevicesController {


        @RequestMapping(value = "/devices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {


             return "devices";  
        }
        ..
    }
```

and this is the location of the devices.jsp:

and inside /webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/devices.jsp

but http://runnerp10.codenvycorp.com:56965/sigfox/devices does not redirect to devices.jsp, I see a HTTP 404 (?)

Comment: is your `spring-servlet.xml` under WEB-INF ? Also , does it work fine on your local server?

Comment: indeed, spring-servlet.xml & web.xml is under WEB-INF and working fine

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada on the line after <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> in your web.xml, add this:<init-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>classpath:path/to/your/spring-servlet.xml </param-value>
  </init-param> also need to add <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener> after the <servlet-mapping> tags in web.xml

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada now your spring-servlet.xml will be scanned and the prefix/suffix values will help to find and resolve your '/devices' URL

Comment: I just added <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml </param-value> 
   </init-param>
   <listener> 
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
    </listener>

Comment: but i got this Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Comment: I've tried , but same error   :-(